# Append text to the beginning of each line

Tags: powershell

I need to modify a server activity report that I send out to remote users.  Instead of them looking up their clients' license numbers, I now have to append this information to the report sent out each morning.  I know POSH can do this, but I haven't had any formal training with it and I'm only familiar with what I've had to create for specific tasks.

I have a csv file with 2 headers LIC, and CLIENT.  The log file begins each line with a 5-digit number that corresponds to a value in the LIC column.  I need to append the value for CLIENT in the column before it's LIC value.  Does anyone have any ideas about where to start building a function that queries the csv file and creates another log file for my report processor to send out?  Thanks in advance for your time!

The csv looks like:

```
LIC,CLIENT
12345,Client1
54321,Client2
34251,Client3
```

The log currently looks like:

```
12345_file.txt,9/11/18,08:15:45
54321_file.txt,9/10/18,11:46:55
```

I would like the log to look like:

```
Client1,12345_file.txt,9/11/18,08:15:45
Client2,54321_file.txt,9/10/18,11:46:55
```

Comment: No need for formal training to get started or get a solid baseline with PS, you can do this via all the free training vids on Microsoft Virtual Academy, MSDN Channel9 and Youtube. We are all glad to help, but you have show us what you've tried and show errors you've encountered. What you are asking for is for someone here to write this for you without any work from your end and that is really frowned upon. What you are asking for is very basic stuff. It's an Get-Content or Import-Csv, match and replace string effort. You can see examples in the built-in help files.

Comment: I sincerely apologize.  I didn't realize this was in violation of standards.  I have taped together several snippets without success, but haven't tackled it from scratch.  Back to the training board.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, but, from time to time, folks will just jump in and do stuff for things. especially if they already have something in the stash to pass on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example script:

```
$licenseFile = "licenses.csv"
$logfile = "logfile.txt"
$newLogfile = "logfile2.txt"

$licenseRows = Import-Csv $licenseFile

Import-Csv $logFile -Header "Filename","Date","Time" | ForEach-Object {
  $row = $_
  @(
    ($licenseRows | Where-Object { $_.LIC -eq ($row.Filename -split "_")[0] }).CLIENT
    $row.Filename
    $row.Date
    $row.Time
  ) -join ","
} | Out-File $newLogfile
```

Of course, change the 3 filenames at the top to meet your requirements.

(This script assumes only one client number per license number and that there's a match in the log file.)

Comment: Thanks!  I have some research to do so I can understand how you put this together.  Some of it I get, some I'll have to look up.  "Input!" --Johnny 5

Comment: I split the pieces up and plugged them into my report script and it fired off output this morning exactly what the boss asked for.  Thanks again!

Comment: If my answer is what you're using, why mark the other response as the answer? (Or did you respond in the wrong place?)

Comment: Heh, just started using this site.  I responded in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Clients=import-csv "c:\temp\client.txt"

import-csv "c:\temp\log.txt" -Header FileName, Date1, Time1 | %{

$Client=$Clients | where Lic -eq ($_.FileName -split '_')[0] | select -first 1

   if ($Client -ne $null)
   {
      Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $Client.CLIENT -Name Client
      $_ 
   }

} | export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoType
```